# configuring Selenium driver to use Socks5 proxy

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, socks

I'm trying to use my Socks5 proxy while using Selenium web driver here is my code :

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "dependencies/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Proxy prx =new Proxy() ;
        prx.setSocksVersion(5);
        prx.setSocksProxy("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000");
        prx.setSocksPassword("5xxxxS") ;
        prx.setSocksUsername("VxxxxW") ;
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("start-minimized");
        options.setCapability("proxy", prx);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // issue here
```

I'm having the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add proxy server arguments to `ChromeOptions`:

```
String host = "shadowsocks6.freeproxy.center";
String port = "8989";
String socks5User = "SOCKS_USER";
String socks5Pass = "SOCKS_Pass";

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=socks5://" + host + ":" + port);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-auth=" + socks5User + ":" + socks5Pass);
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

You can refer to [selenium-tiny-projects](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/tree/main/ConfigureBrowserProxy) for complete source code

Comment: perfect answer , thanks Hana

Comment: Doesn't work, the proxy has error `net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Comment: First of all test if your proxy works with cURL `timeout 5 curl -x socks5://localhost:8080` .... try replacing localhost:8080 with the host and port of youe desired proxy

Comment: It works. You have made my day ! 2 days actually :)